# function to return an individual value from a crosstab dataframe in python

Tags: python, crosstab

I am trying to return a value from a crosstab dataframe in python.  I have a dataset with 2 columns. 1 with probabilities of ebola called prob and the other with 1's or 0's indicating the actual diagnosis of ebola called ebola. I want to add a new column to this dataframe Col3 based on a cutoff probability threshold from 0.1 - 0.2 which will be the only argument to my function e.g 0.10,0.11 etc. I then want to return the percentage of false positives only from that crosstab dataframe I create.  I can do this without a function but I am getting errors when I try to create a function. My code I have tried is below.

```
def cutoff(x):
    ebola['Col3'] = (ebola['prob'] > x).astype(int)
    df = pd.crosstab(ebola.Col3,ebola.ebola).apply(lambda r: r/len(ebola),axis=1)
return df.ix[1,0]
```

If I run this line by line not in a function I get values. Can anyone see what is wrong with this as a function?

Comment: In the current representation of the function you forgot a tab before the return statement

Comment: Thank you that worked great.